# Why Does MongoDB Return value:null Error When Upserting New Document with findOneAndUpdate()?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

During the first time a new stock is queried, when the document doesn't exist, it adds the new document but then returns an error with value=null. I followed the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) and put **'returnNewDocument':true** but it's still not working.. 

How can I return the new document when it upserts a new document please?

```js
let doc = await col.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'stock': stock}, 
  {'$addToSet': {'likes': ip}}, 
  {'upsert': true, 'returnNewDocument': true}
);
```

returns the following error

```js
Updated Document: {"lastErrorObject":{"n":1,"updatedExisting":false,"upserted":"5e5dbb8bf12e9343ec7a9b88"},"value":null,"ok":1,"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":"6799797218074165249","signature":{"hash":"sd5UrKaesKhMqtQEHBKTlE4Lovw=","keyId":"6794816602199031810"}},"operationTime":"6799797218074165249"}
```

P.S. Sry don't know how to wrap the code so it shows properly. Open to advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the stage $addToSet to $set

```html
try {
db.grades.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "stock" : stock },
   { $set: { "likes" : ip}},
   { upsert:true, returnNewDocument : true }
);
}
catch (e){
   print(e);
}
```

Now use this code...

Comment: Thanks. But $set still gives me an error pretty much same as above... also I need the $addToSet functionality because it adds onto an array if not existing but doesn't add if it exists. $set seems to be different.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a exception handling, if any error you can able to track them...remove the single quotes to upsert and returnNewDocument

Comment: Sorry, appreciate the help but this doesn't solve my problem. $set is a different functionality to $addToSet afaik. Also $set still doesn't return the new document upserted.

Comment: The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.  

The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.

Comment: Yeah I need to keep my $addToSet functionality. Any way to still get the new doc even with $addToSet?